# Monitoring Audio device changes (3.5mm jack) using Pycaw (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a projetc where I monitor the Audio device changes and set master volume to zero when the headphones are unplugged from 3.5mm jack. I am working on windows

How to count the list of devices before and after headphones are removed ?

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
import time


def set_master_volume_to_zero():
    global devices1
    devices1 = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices1.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume1 = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    volume1.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-65.0, None)
    
    
#def set_master_volume_to_defult():
    #devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    #interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    #volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    #default_volume = volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel()
    #print(default_volume)

def monitor_device_changes():
    global devices1
    devices2 = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    if devices2.GetCount() > devices1.GetCount():
        set_master_volume_to_zero()
    
def main():
    while True:
        monitor_device_changes()
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to count the devices1 and devices2 because to my knowledge it's a list of devices but to no avail.

Comment: `devices1.GetCount()` will fail, because your code does that before it has assigned `devices1` (which would only happen when `set_master_volume_to_zero` is called).

Comment: So what can I do?
Any suggestions to do it another way?